# Azure devops eq returns false no matter what the variable value is

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to do an equality check on a variable value in azure pipelines yaml file but it keeps returning False no matter what the input is. This is the variable stored in the library,
[image]

Then I tried to echo the response like this

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


variables:
  - group: sample
  - name: skipBuild
    value: '$(skip-build)'


stages:
  - stage: Test_stage
    condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/test')
    jobs:
      - job: Test
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo "Check eq('false', 'false') ${{eq('false', 'false')}} eq('${{ variables.skipBuild }}', 'false') ${{ eq('${{ variables.skipBuild }}', 'false') }}"
```

The output is this,
[image]

So what I have done above is 1st I hardcoded the value in the eq('false', 'false') and that returns true, but when it's fed with the actual variable it returns false. You can see the variable is correctly read inside the second eq output and doesn't seem to have an issue in conversion as well, since both the expected and the actual are strings. So how can I overcome this issue. Why do I keep getting False when doing a variable checking even it should return true?

Comment: where do you require to use the `skipBuild` variable eventually? have you used it in an `if` expression or `condition`?

Comment: Yes @Sibtain, I used in both but it doesn't return the expected results. Thats why I tried to echo the results and see what's the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `${{ variables.skipBuild }}` is a compile time expression and the value of your variable is not known at compile time (because it's sourced from a variable group).

If you set the value of the `skipBuild` variable to a runtime expression then this will be evaluated at runtime and will be able to see the value of your `skip-build` variable.

Here's a modified version of your above pipeline showcasing this:

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  - group: sample
  - name: skipBuild
    value: $[eq(variables['skip-build'], 'False')] # runtime expression

steps:
- script: |
    echo $(skipBuild) # outputs 'True'
```

For more info on runtime vs compile time expressions in Azure Pipelines see MS docs here: [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops).